# Plot a curved line on an image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

lets say I have an image with some black pixels.
I know all the coordinates of the black pixels and im looking for the yellow line.

given: coordinates of the black pixel in my image.

looking for: the yellow polynomial which fits best to the black pixels

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.imread("foo.jpg")
#search for the black pixels and save the coordinates.

#coordinates of all pixels (example)
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0]) 
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0]) 
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
p = np.poly1d(z)
```

If I understand everything correctly, now I created a polynomial (yellow line on the image) with `np.poly1d()`.
But how can I draw this on my bgr_img?

Edit:

this is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("white_foo.jpg") #1000x1000 pixel

#lets say these are my black pixels in a white image.
x = np.array([122, 224, 210, 350,  380,  250, 490, 623, 711, 819, 900])
y = np.array([536, 480, 390, 366, 270, 240, 180, 210, 280, 400, 501])

#calculate the coefficients.
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
lspace = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)

#here I want to draw the polynomial which I calculated with polyfit on my image

cv2.imshow("test", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: see this https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: alternatively, check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703105/convert-matplotlib-figure-to-numpy-array-of-same-shape/55704409#55704409)

Comment: @user8190410 I looked into the docks but I can't draw a polynom :/

Comment: @warped I get always a lot of errors.. :/

Comment: You have 10 black dots in your image but only 6 pairs of coordinates in your arrays?  Your pixels are all shown with positive x and y in the diagram, but your array has negative y values? If you are trying to confuse me, it worked ;-)

Comment: When you say you have an image with some black pixels, I guess you mean you have an image that is largely white with a few black pixels here and there, rather than an image that is made of black pixels?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The code is only an example... The x and y coordinates in the code are all fictional! :)

Comment: You are supposed to provide a **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example** of your code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve That means we should be able to run it.You can't hope to fit a 2nd degree polynomial to a sine wave.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I have a white image image with some black pixel here and there and I know all the coordinates of them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added my code.. :)

Comment: Given some polynomial, how would you plot a graph of it using a pencil, ruler and a piece of graph paper? Then translate the algorithm you used to actual code.

Answer (score 5):

A quick google turned up: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines

and this: [Opencv polylines function in python throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241830/opencv-polylines-function-in-python-throws-exception)

In any case, you need to evaluate the polynomial at the points you're interested in, then format those points appropriately (polylines wants them in a int32 container, formatted like `[[x_1, y_1], [x_2, y_2], ... , [x_n, y_n]]`). Then just call the function.

```
draw_x = lspace
draw_y = np.polyval(z, draw_x)   # evaluate the polynomial

draw_points = (np.asarray([draw_x, draw_y]).T).astype(np.int32)   # needs to be int32 and transposed

cv2.polylines(img, [draw_points], False, (0,0,0))  # args: image, points, closed, color
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

I would do it by creating and reusing an AxesSubplot object from the matplotlib.pyplot library.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("white_foo.jpg") #1000x1000 pixel

#lets say these are my black pixels in a white image.
y = np.array([122, 224, 210, 350,  380,  250, 490, 623, 711, 819, 900])
x = np.array([536, 480, 390, 366, 270, 240, 180, 210, 280, 400, 501])

# Initilaize y axis
lspace = np.linspace(0,  out_img.shape[0]-1, out_img.shape[0])

#calculate the coefficients.
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

#calculate x axis
line_fitx = z[0]*lspace**2 + z[1]*lspace+ z[2]

# Create axes figure
ax1 = plt.axes()

#Show image
ax1.imshow(out_img, aspect='auto')

#Draw Polynomial over image
ax1.plot(line_fitx,lspace, color='blue');
```

### Solution 2

Another way to do it is to create a white image (2d NumPy array of zeros) with the same shape as the image and using the plot position as indexes give color to the pixels. See below

```
verts = np.array(list(zip(lspace.astype(int),line_fitx.astype(int))))
polynom_image[tuple(verts.T)] = [255,0,0]

# Create axes figure
ax2 = plt.axes()
#Show image
ax2.imshow(polynom_image)
```

Then the `cv2.addWeighted` function could be used to merge them into a single image.

```
result = cv2.addWeighted(polynom_image, 1, und_images[0], 0.5, 0)
```

The drawback that I see with this second method is the lack of control over the plot, especially the line witdth.

### Solution 3

Using the `cv2.polylines` function. Note that it modifies the original img (numpy array).

```
verts = np.array(list(zip(line_fitx.astype(int),lspace.astype(int))))
cv2.polylines(img,[verts],False,(0,255,255),thickness=3)
ax2 = plt.axes()
ax2.imshow(img)
```